# multi gpu also for viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

does having more than one gpu also have an impact on speed of the rendered viewport in cycles ? (renderd viewport i mean the traditional shift z render )

or multi gpu rendering is only okay for the f12 final render ?

and about eevee ? doest is support multi gpu for viewport as well as f12 final render ?

thanks, im planning to upgrade my pc and i want to be sure before i make the purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, multiple GPU's will also be used for the shift+z viewport render.

No, multiple GPU support is not planned for Eevee yet.
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-will-eevee-support-multi-gpu/625
It will just use your "display" card.

Answer (score 0):

I've had mixed results with vastly dissimilar GPU's in the viewport while running cycles. In my final renders I enable all 3 of my GPU's: 980ti, 960, and k1200. The latter two devices are comparably slow, but they do reduce render times by at least 30% (somewhat useful). However, they add nothing to the interactive viewport. In fact, if I leave the 960 and k1200 enabled, the viewport is 4x slower than having only the 980ti enabled.

The viewport seems to be only as fast as your slowest GPU. It's almost as if the real time cycles needs equivalent GPU's to see any benefit of using more than one?  Can anyone confirm this?  Would another 980ti actually halve my viewport rendering times?